# Serve video that is encrypted on the server and decrypted in browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, encryption, mobile-safari, drm

I would like to create an application where a video is encrypted before hand and placed on a server, the user can then stream this encrypted video and play it back (without downloading the entire video). The video is encrypted on the server so the administrator has no knowledge of the content of the video apart from aproximate runtime.

I have looked into things like ClearKey however this is only supported on Chrome and Firefox and I would like to support mobile browsers like safari on IOS, which does not support clearkey but instead uses it's own DRM system.

I wondered if there were any open source projects people were aware of that perform similar tasks across a variety of browsers. If there isn't would someone mind giving me a pointer as to how I might go about implementing this?

I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this question I'm not sure where else I could ask this.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: To clarify I don't need the traditional features of DRM such as the user being prevented from downloading the video

Comment: "To clarify I don't need" … what *do* you need? What is the goal of using encryption? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: @Quentin So myself, the server administrator, has no knowledge of the content of the videos apart from their aproximate run time.